# Using the Method of Characteristics to Determine Invariant Solutions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The PDE I want to solve, by finding invariants and reducing order is:
$$
u_t-uu_x-u_{xxx}=0
$$

- One solution is found as follows:

**1. Solve $\frac{du}{1}=\frac{dx}{t}$**

Since we don't have a $dt$ term, we set the first invariant as $y=t$

I solve:
\begin{align} 
\frac{du}{1}&=\frac{dx}{-t}\\
u  &= \frac{-1}{t}x + C\\
\end{align}

The second invariant is given as $v =tu + x$ which can be rewritten as : $u = \frac{1}{t}v - \frac{1}{t}x$

**2. Now determine $u_x, u_{xxx}, u_t$ in terms of $\frac{dv}{dy}$**

\begin{align}
u_x &= \frac{-1}{t}\\
&= \frac{-1}{y}\\
u_{xxx} &= 0\\
u_t &= \frac{1}{y^2}(yv_y-v+x)\\
\end{align}

**3. Sub $u_{xxx}, u_x, u_t$ into the original ODE**
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{y^2}(yv_y-v+x) + \frac{1}{y^2}(v-x)-0&=0\\
yv_y - v + x + v - x &= 0\\
y\frac{dv}{dy} &=0\\
v &= \alpha \\
\end{align}

So the solution we get is $u = \frac{\alpha - x}{t}$

I now want to repeat the process, but now I want to solve:
$$
\frac{i\omega dx}{\sin(i\omega x)} = \frac{\omega^2dt}{3t\cos(i\omega x)} = \frac{-i\omega du}{2\sin(i \omega u)}
$$

I solve:
\begin{align}
\frac{i \omega dx}{\sin(i \omega x)}&=\frac{\omega^2 dt}{3t\cos(i \omega x)}\\
\frac{3i}{\omega}\cot(i \omega x)dx&=\frac{1}{t}dt\\
\frac{3\ln(\sinh(\omega x))}{\omega^2} &= \ln t + \ln C\\
\ln (\sinh(\omega x)^{\frac{3}{\omega^2}} - \ln T &= \ln C\\
\end{align}

So the first invariant is:
$$
r = \frac{\sinh(\omega x)^{\frac{3}{\omega ^2}}}{t}
$$

Now I solve:
\begin{align}
\frac{i \omega dx}{\sin(i \omega x)} &= \frac{-i \omega du}{2 \sin(i \omega u)}\\
\frac{-2dx}{\sin(i \omega x)} &= \frac{du}{\sin (i \omega u)}\\
\frac{-2i\ln(\operatorname{csch}(\omega x) + \coth( \omega x))}{w} +\ln C &= \frac{i\ln(\operatorname{csch}(\omega u) + \coth(\omega u))}{w}\\
\end{align}

How can I isolate my constant and get the next invariant?

Comment: This is the [KdV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation), for which you might find what you are looking for online (the method of characteristics is probably not a good starting point)

Comment: I am required to use this method of solving.  I am not looking for existing solutions, rather I am trying to determine "new" solutions.